# Get selected item from react-google-places-autocomplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-places-api

I'm trying to get the selected address from react-google-places-autocomplete in React Js but I don't know how to get the value. Sorry to bother you and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your function, you should have a **useState** hook for the value you'd like to get. Something like this:

```
    const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
```

Then, in your JSX you'll have something similar to the following:

```
                    <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
                        selectProps={{
                            location,
                            onChange: setLocation,
                          }}                        
                        query={{key: YOUR_API_KEY}}
                        fetchDetails={true}
                        onFail={error => console.log(error)}
                      />
```

Now, each time the user clicks on the auto suggested address by Google Places, your **location** variable will store a map of the information returned. To get the value of the address, you'll need to just grab it using the "label" key.

> **location["label"]**

IOW, this will return the selected address.